# matrix multiplication using @ or numpy.dot() is givng wrong results at higher values.Why?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

Here input a is given in comments in the next block and the answer which I have got using numpy also gives me same result.

[image]

The actual answer should be

[image]

If you want the real context where I am using this is the drive [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jCQT6uCTqx7JeKemYPIW3iM8d3F_ZJ-_/view?usp=sharing) for the file

Comment: What dtype are the elements? Looks like some kind of integer overflow issue.

Comment: @Jasmijn all are integers .If I am using normal addition to calculate the there is no integer over flow occurrence at same value calculations(Actually I am using this to calculate Fibonacci series). If I implement my own mat mul it turns out to be fine But  Using matrix multiplication by @ or np.dot()  I am facing problem why ?

Comment: Python itself has big integers, but values in numpy arrays are fixed size integers, that's why I asked about the dtype (which is a numpy concept).

Comment: You can check it with `a.dtype`. If it is `"int32"`, you may get better results if you define `a = array([[not typing all those numbers]], dtype="int64")` before the matrix multiplication.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the numbers in the original matrix a is too large. So that the output is incorrect.

To deal with this problem, first scale down the numbers in the matrix by a number first. Then run the matrix multiplication. After that scale up back the number to the matrix. This will give you the results.

The following is the code:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[3524578, 2178309],[2178309, 1346269]])
a = a / 10000
b = np.dot(a, a) *10000
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[[1.71676802e+09 1.06102099e+09]
 [1.06102099e+09 6.55747032e+08]]
```

Comment: If I use my own matrix Multiplication Function I have no problem with the result. But I want to Know Why it is happening different with two different ways of calculation. Why there is overflow in one way and not in other?

Comment: How did you set the matrix Multiplication Function? But what I can see is that using numpy will cause the overflow error. So to deal with the overflow problem in numpy. Scale down the matrix first.